# Stream support in Odata V4

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

What is the recommended way in handling file stream GET, POST AND DELETE operations. I got following link on how to do it but its for V3 version. While porting this solution to OData V4 Iran into bunch of issues which raised following questions.

1. Is the Stream support is available in Odata V4?
2. If Yes, How do I set HasStream property on IEdmEntityType. The IEdmModel.SetHasDefaultStream seems like deprecated now in V4.
3. Is there any sample which explains how I can go ahead with enabling POST, GET  for stream in OData V4 Service.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrtechnocal/archive/2013/10/31/media-resource-support-for-odata-in-web-api.aspx

If this feature not yet built up in web apis yet do we have any future release plans for this?

-Samir

Comment: Any pointers from experts

Comment: I put together a sample netcoreapp2.1 repo: https://github.com/kevin-osborne/ODataSample

Comment: @user326608 that is not a standard stream, have you seen this?
https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.01/cn03/new-in-odata-v4.01-cn03.html#sec_NewexpandofStreamPropertiesandMediaR

Comment: @Norcino sorry, I hadn't seen it. I wrote some server pieces in net45 so that clients written via https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client could access a binary (pdf) version of an entity. Later I ported those bits to core and verified they worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Opened an issue on GitHub, please refer to https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/328#issuecomment-101205048.